# Express "Error: Access denied for user 'qwer'@'localhost' (using password: YES),sqlState: '28000' " but 'root' user can createPool

Tags: javascript, mysql, express

#### Backend projects are written in Express (Node 16.0.0)

The code in sqlPool.js (the file specifically used to provide MySQL creation connection function) is

```
const mysql = require('mysql');
const sqlPool = mysql.createPool({
    host: 'localhost',
    port: 3306,
    user: 'qwer',
    password: 'qwer@0.0.0-MySQL',
    database: 'gl1_ui',
    connectionLimit: 16
});
```

It doesn't work. `"Error: Access denied for user 'qwer'@'localhost' (using password: YES)`

But if I use 'root' user to createPool like this:

```
const mysql = require('mysql');
const sqlPool = mysql.createPool({
    host: 'localhost',
    port: 3306,
    user: 'root',
    password: 'root',
    database: 'gl1_ui',
    connectionLimit: 16
});
```

It's fine

The 'qwer' user's details in MySQL :

```
CREATE USER `qwer`@`%` IDENTIFIED WITH mysql_native_password PASSWORD EXPIRE NEVER;

GRANT Alter, Alter Routine, Create, Create Routine, Create Temporary Tables, Create View, Delete, Event, Execute, Index, Insert, Lock Tables, References, Select, Show View, Trigger, Update ON `gl1_ui`.* TO `qwer`@`%`;

GRANT Create View, Delete, Event, Execute, File, Grant Option, Index, Insert, Process, References, Reload, Select, Show Databases, Show View, Shutdown, Trigger, Update ON *.* TO `qwer`@`%`;
```

I tried to  `FLUSH PRIVILEGES;` but nothing changed.

Answer (score 0):

All right.
I solved this problem alone.
The character '@' in password cannot be passed correctly. But I don't know why does it.
When I deleted this character, the problem was solved.
**So I should avoid setting the '@' character in SQL password when the project using the express framework**